# Can MD5ing all the files in a table cause a memory leak?

Tags: java

I'm running this code with the FastMD5 library. Could it lead to memory leaks, or does it seem OK?

```
File[] directory = new File("/PATH/TO/FOLDER/WITH/LOTS/OF/FILES").listFiles();

    for(int i = 0; i < directory.length;i++){

    System.out.println(MD5.asHex(MD5.getHash(directory[i])));

    }
```

Comment: Do you have a reason to suspect a memory leak?  There are many tools in Java that interact with the virtual machine and can show you a graph of memory usage in real-time.

Comment: @toto2 It's really weird. About 2.5GB of free memory turns into inactive in the run of the program.

Answer (score 1):

In Java you have to do so much hard work to leak memory (someone will say not closing stream, but that's another story).

I think you have a C programming background. So you are thinking of `memory leak`. Forget it there is JVM for you.

And use enhanced for loop in Java as much as you can...

```
for(File file : directory) {
    System.out.println(MD5.asHex(MD5.getHash(file)));
}
```

Comment: For some reason I lose memory when I run my program. It's like the files are being saved to memory.
You're wrong :) I'm a pretty new developer. I'm losing my mind over this bug.

Comment: @ItaiHay: Java will likely grab a bunch of memory anyway.  GC typically doesn't run immediately, and you're reading in mass amounts of data (probably to a new array each time) and even the list of files might be huge.  Unless you're actually running into OOMEs, don't worry about it; the memory usage will level off.

Comment: @cHao It's segnificant.  2.5GB of free memory turnes into inactive in a matter of 1 minute (the programs run time)

Comment: @ItaiHay: And your app crashes at that point?